# beautiful soup find function to scrape number off google

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

Ive just finished watching a tutorial on beautiful soup and thought I'd use it to try and scrape some data from google.

I've just [googled coronavirus UK](https://www.google.com/search?q=coronavrius+uk&rlz=1C1CHBF_en-GBGB813GB813&oq=cor&aqs=chrome.0.69i59l2j0j69i57j35i39j69i64j69i60l2.1384j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) and wanted to scrape the current confirmed cases number.

On the upper right hand side of the web page is a box which shows the number of confirmed cases in the UK. Upon inspecting the element I found it to be located in this block:

```
<td jsname="VBiLTe" class="dZdtsb QmWbpe ZDeom" data-absolute-value="276332" data-is-data-cell="true" 
data-per-million-value="4258.258906030955" data-vfs="276332"><div class="amyZLb">Confirmed</div><div 
class="m7B03"><div jsname="fUyIqc"><span>276K</span></div><div jsname="KBqmYc" style="display:none">
<span>4,258</span></div></div><div class="h5Hgwe"><div jsname="fUyIqc">+<span>1,570</span></div></div>
</td>
```

The data-vfs key in the above code block holds the value I want to scrape. I thought this code would work to scrape the value.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

source = requests.get("https://www.google.com/search?q=coronavrius+uk&rlz=1C1CHBF_en-GBGB813GB813&oq=cor&aqs=chrome.0.69i59l2j0j69i57j35i39j69i64j69i60l2.1384j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8").text
soup = BeautifulSoup(source,'lxml')

test=soup.find("td",class_="dZdtsb QmWbpe ZDeom")
print(test["data-vfs"])
```

However, test is returned as none, (which gives an error upon running the code) implying nothing was found? I've been trying to figure out why for ages but nothing comes to mind. How do I modify the arguments in find to scrape the number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To obtain information from pages served by Google, you need to specify `User-Agent` header.

For example:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url ='https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=corona+virus+uk'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:76.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/76.0'}

soup = BeautifulSoup( requests.get(url, headers=headers).content, 'html.parser' )

table1 = soup.select_one('div:has(span:contains("United Kingdom")) + table')
table2 = soup.select_one('div:has(span:contains("Worldwide")) + table')

print('UK:')
print('-'*80)
for td in table1.select('td'):
    print(td.get_text(strip=True, separator=' '))

print()

print('World:')
print('-'*80)
for td in table2.select('td'):
    print(td.get_text(strip=True, separator=' '))
```

Prints:

```
UK:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Confirmed 276K 4,258 + 1,570
Recovered -
Deaths 39,045 602 + 0

World:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Confirmed 6.06M 860 + 123K
Recovered -
Deaths 371K 53 + 4,000
```

EDIT: Running the code as of 6th July 2020 prints:

```
UK:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Confirmed 285K 4,398 + 624
Recovered -
Deaths 44,220 681 + 67

World:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Confirmed 11.4M 1,621 + 203K
Recovered 6.16M 874
Deaths 534K 76 + 5,193
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, just 2 queries regarding the above.

Firstly, how would I know whether some other page I am scraping from will require a user-agent header? I don't know when I am supposed to specify this. 

Secondly, is there anything wrong with my code example? Lets say a user-agent header is not required. Would the format soup.find(element, class_="class name") work to select that code block which I have put in to my question. Sorry if this sounds vague, I just want to check If I have understood how to use the find function.

Comment: @V.Jain Regarding the `User-Agent` header, it's trial-and-error. Every page handles it differently. I know from experience, that Google requires it, but if you get some blank response, then try to change the `User-Agent` (this is the first thing I do). Regarding the `soup.find()` - yes, it should work. For me, using CSS selectors is more natural, but `find()` and `find_all()` are both valid methods :)

Comment: It works perfectly after including the header :). I will have to google css selectors. Its the first Ive heard of this. Will reading the BeautifulSoup documentation include using CSS headers?

Comment: @V.Jain There is section about [CSS selectors](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) in official bs4 documentation. I recommend to learn both `.find()` and `.select()` methods - they are both useful in their respective way.

Comment: I was having trouble with some other concept and came back to this answer. I didnt try to run your code the first time I saw the answer since the user agent suggestion worked to fix the code. This time I tried to run it with css selectors exactly as shown above and I get an error:
`NotImplementedError: Only the following pseudo-classes are implemented: nth-of-type.`. Why does your code not work for me?

Comment: I am getting a new error after updating to bs4 4.9.1 which is `AttributeError: 'HTMLParserTreeBuilder' object has no attribute 'store_line_numbers'`. Can you re run the code above and check if it works fine for you?

Comment: @V.Jain Yes, running the code prints correct numbers - see my edit.

Comment: This seems to be a problem with my parser, Ive copy pasted the above code exactly and run it with my user agent, but I keep getting the error in the previous comment. Is there anyway you know how to fix it?

Comment: @V.Jain I cannot reproduce your problem. Try to change `User-Agent` header, do `print(soup)` and see if you aren't getting blocked (captcha etc...)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that the "jsname" indicates that this block of the web page is loaded dynamically by javascript after the main page loads. BeautifulSoup as you're using it will download the source, but not execute any of the javascript on a page before parsing it.

You might want to look at "Selenium" which is a headless browser, or learn BeautifulSoup with static pages that are from a simpler source. For example, Google is getting that data from somewhere, find the source and scrape that page.

Good Luck!